# Input-groups in one row not working in bootstrap v5 grid anymore?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal window with a grid, that worked fine in `bootstrap-4`:
https://jsfiddle.net/y6xg7823/11/

The modal window should show two `input-group`s next to each other in one row.

Migrating to `bootstrap-5`, the grid is not respected anymore, and the inputs are simply placed below each other:
https://jsfiddle.net/o2w6cqms/14/
Why?

```
<div class="modal-body">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row row-cols-2">
         <div class="col input-group mb-3">
            <span class="input-group-text" for="test1">Test1</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="test1">
         </div>
         <div class="col input-group mb-3">
            <span class="input-group-text" for="test2">Test2</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="test2">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

According to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/#row-columns, `.row-cols-*` on the parent row are simply to set the number of cols to render in the layout. I don't get it why it's not working anymore in v5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the image below the class input-group is putting the width to 100%, overwriting the .row-cols-2>* selector width, remove input-group selector or put the input-group as a child of the div with the col selector.
[image]

```html
<div class="col">
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text" for="test1">Test1</span>
              </div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="test1">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col ">
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text" for="test1">Test2</span>
              </div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="test2">
            </div>
          </div>
```